# How to startup / shutdown TwinCAT System from console / C# program?

Tags: c#, twincat

How could I start/restart/shutdoown TwinCAT System runtime from console or C# application? I need a functionality equivalent to the TwinCAT toolbar buttons System Start/Restart on the lower right.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished be accomplished using the C# .net ADS library. To change the TwinCAT runtime between Config and Run, connect to the System Service ADS port (port 10000) and set the state to `AdsState.Run` or `AdsState.Config`.

All valid state values can be found [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_adsnetref/4017527051.html&id=584215737148817938). All the port values can be found [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_adsnetref/4017657099.html&id=7761548341739913127).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create a new instance of class TcAdsClient
        TcAdsClient tcClient = new TcAdsClient();

        try
        {
            // Connect to TwinCAT System Service port 10000
            tcClient.Connect(AmsPort.SystemService);
            // Send desired state
            tcClient.WriteControl(new StateInfo(AdsState.Config, tcClient.ReadState().DeviceState));

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        finally
        {
            tcClient.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TwinCAT automation interface](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcautomationinterface/html/tcsysman_automation.htm&id=972389352036000631), which is accessible by [linking the automation interface DLL](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcautomationinterface/html/tcsysman_installation.htm&id=7306455922629994658) from a C#/.NET-program.

Specifically, to start/restart TwinCAT you use the [ITcSysManager::StartRestartTwinCAT](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcautomationinterface/html/ITcSysManager_StartRestartTwinCAT.htm&id=) - method

Comment: Thank you, I have linked the automation interface DLL but when I instance the `systemManager = new TcSysManager();` as seen in the TwnCAT documentation  it throws me a runtime error of _missing method exception: no constructor without parameters defined for the object_. But I can neither put a constructor with parameters because it says it does not exist and gives me a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

TcXaeMgmt needs to be installed to PS v4.0+
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/TcXaeMgmt/3.2.21

Than in Powershell type:
Set-AdsState Stop
or
Set-AdsState Start

Details here:
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_ads_ps_tcxaemgmt/4130762891.html&id=4912948515382920501

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a small updated version of code that restarts the TwinCAT on remote/local PLC/PC/PAC:

```
using TwinCAT.Ads;
using TwinCAT.Ads.Extensions;
string ads = "127.0.0.1.1.1";// use your address here
AdsClient adsClient = new AdsClient();
try
{
    // Connect to TwinCAT System Service port
    Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to address {ads} port {AmsPort.SystemService}.");
    adsClient.Connect(new AmsNetId(ads), AmsPort.SystemService);
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected successfully.");

    AdsState currentMode = adsClient.ReadState().AdsState;
    if (currentMode != AdsState.Config)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Switching to \"config\" mode");
        adsClient.SetAdsState(AdsStateCommand.Reconfig, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(31), false, false);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Starting TwinCAT.");
    adsClient.SetAdsState(AdsStateCommand.Reset, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(31), false, false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This code is based on the answer from Seth on Jan 20 2019.